# Não consigo instalar o IBGEPesq no R para ler as PNADs

Tags: r, versionamento, instalador, packages

Acabei de baixar a PNAD 2013 do IBGE -- e fui tentar abri-la com o pacote para R que o próprio IBGE elaborou, o IBGEPesq. Ele está disponível como arquivo .zip, neste endereço:

ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Trabalho_e_Rendimento/Pesquisa_Nacional_por_Amostra_de_Domicilios_anual/microdados/2013/Leitura_em_R.zip

Baixei ele no meu working directory. E executei:

```
    install.packages("IBGEPesq_1.0-4.zip",
                     repos=NULL)

    library(IBGEPesq)
```

Mas aí recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
    Error: package ‘IBGEPesq’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it
```

Obviamente, já tentei re-instalar. E também já executei isso aqui:

```
    # Para atualizar os demais pacotes
    update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)

    # Por recomendação em um fórum (não entendi bem por quê) 
    install.packages('codetools')
```

E mesmo assim, a re-instalação não funciona. O mesmo erro retorna. 
Estou utilizando um Windows 7 e os dados da sessão do R são:

```
    > sessionInfo()
    R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

    locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
    [3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
    [5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] tools_3.1.1
```

De antemão, agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Tente refazer o procedimento utilizando o R x32.

Comment: Também não dá certo, Athos...

Comment: Faltou eu observar que o erro que vc recebeu informa que o R tem q ser de uma versão anterior ao 3.0.0. Acho q no R 2.14.x x32 já roda. Veja se vai

Comment: @Athos, provavelmente numa versão anterior do R deve rodar. Mas não vale à pena fazer um downgrade só pra rodar esse pacote. A questão é justamente fazer funcionar numa versão atual...

Comment: @RogerioJB acho que o IBGEPesq já era, pelo que eu tenho acompanhado o pacote foi descontinuado. Se eles disponibilizassem o código fonte nós poderíamos adapta-lo facilmente, mas pelo que eu sei ele não está disponível em lugar nenhum. Apesar de que hoje existem funções para leitura que são até mais rápidas que as do IBGEPesq.

Comment: @FlavioBarros mesmo se o tar.gz não estiver disponível, é possível ver o código fonte das funções também. Por exemplo, você pode instalar o pacote e rodar `ls(getNamespace("IBGEPesq"), all.names=TRUE)` para pegar todas as funções disponíveis. A partir daí é só chamar `edit(IBGEPesq:::nome_funcao)` para abrir um editor de texto com a função. Abs

Comment: Então @Carlos Cinelli, experimente faze-lo com o IBGEPesq, vai ter uma surpresa...inicialmente eu ia utilizar os fontes do pacote para atualiza-lo para o R 3.0.0 na época. Infelizmente não dá, tem código compilado nesse pacote.

Answer (score 3):

Recomendo utilizar o script criado pelo Damico e Djalma, o qual pode ser encontrado [aqui](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/pesquisa%20nacional%20por%20amostra%20de%20domicilios%20%28pnad%29). Já trabalhei bastante com ele e funciona perfeitamente.

Você obtém os dados via: **download all microdata.R**, e então efetua a análise com **single-year - analysis examples.R**.

Lá você também encontrará scripts para a PME, POF e PISA.

Comment: Olá @JVLegend. Sim, conheço os scripts do Damico. São excelentes mesmo. Mas estou experimentando o pacote do próprio IBGE... queria saber como resolver esse problema particular. Mas é bem provável que eles já não estejam interessados em investir nesse pacote...

Answer (score 3):

Eu conheço os script do Damico, mas particularmente eu prefiro a solução que eu vou apresentar aqui. Por conta de os dados da PNAD serem fornecidos como microdados, basta ter o dicionário da pesquisa que a leitura é trivial utilizando qualquer leitor com delimitador. Por razões de desempenho vou utilizar aqui o data.table e uma função em C++ do pacote desc que converte arquivos de texto delimitados em arquivos csv, a fwf2csv(). Depois basta usar a função fread() do data.table que lê csv's super rápido.

Inicialmente você vai precisar do dicionário e dos microdados, ambos os quais podem ser baixados aqui: http://www.ibge.gov.br/home/estatistica/populacao/trabalhoerendimento/pnad2012/microdados.shtm Na planilha "Dicionário de variáveis de domicílios da Pesquisa Básica - 2013.xls" exporte para um CSV as três primeiras colunas: Posição Inicial, Tamanho, Código de variável. No meu caso salvei como dicdom.csv.

Com os microdados na pasta Dados execute o script:

```
#############PREPARAÇÃO DE DADOS##########
library(bit64)
library(data.table)
library(descr)
library(xlsx)

## Criando o dicionário a partir das três primeiras colunas da planilha
dicdom <- read.csv(file = 'dicdom.csv', header=F)
dicdom <- dicdom[complete.cases(dicdom),]
colnames(dicdom) <- c('inicio', 'tamanho', 'variavel')

## Parâmetro com o final de cada campo
end_dom = dicdom$inicio + dicdom$tamanho - 1

## Converte o microdado para um arquivo csv
fwf2csv(fwffile='Dados/DOM2013.txt', csvfile='dadosdom.csv', names=dicdom$variavel, begin=dicdom$inicio, end=end_dom)

## Efetua a leitura do conjunto de dados com o fread do data.table
dadosdom <- fread(input='dadosdom.csv', sep='auto', sep2='auto', integer64='double')
```

E pronto! São 148.697 domicílios, é só verificar com nrow(). Repita o procedimento para os dados das pessoas.

Comment: Um ponto importante a salientar é que existe o pacote DicionariosIBGE (http://arademaker.github.io/blog/2012/09/20/pacote-dicionariosIBGE.html) que já vem com os dicionários de várias PNAD's até 2012. Eu tinha incluído o último dicionário de 2012, mas assim que der vou fazer um pull request para incluir o dicionário da PNAD 2013 também.

Comment: desculpe, isso pode acelerar a importacao um pouco, mas ele nao consegue fundir ou pos-estratificacao dos pesos ou remover os valores em falta.  um exemplo completo deve replicar um coeficiente de variacao do ibge.

Comment: @AnthonyDamico, veja que o objetivo da resposta que eu dei era mostrar um procedimento de leitura dos dados da PNAD,  sem utilizar o IBGEPesq. De qualquer forma nos seus scripts estão disponíveis esses passos seguintes e talvez o ideal seria unir essa forma de leitura ao pós tratamento que você fez. Assim que tiver tempo vou tentar fazer isso. Mas particularmente para essa resposta eu não achei necessário faze-lo. De qualquer forma obrigado pela sugestão.